# Is it possible to export a neural network from R to Excel?

Tags: r, excel, neural-network

I would like to train a neural network in R and use it in Excel. Would it be possible to export a neural network to Excel?

Currently I have made a lineair regression model in R and I can use the coefficients in Excel formulas. I am looking for a similar method with a neural network.

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: no. there is no such thing as coefficients in neural network models, they are more a web of interactions. There is a package called `tidypredict` that translates lm & random forest models into a readable (sql) output - but they are still a long way off working with neural networks. If you want pure predictive power, stick with neural networks. If you want translatability, stick with lm

Comment: @ Shinobi_Atobe So if i understand correctly, i will always need R for making a prediction with the trained neural network. Do you know if there is a possibility to call R from Excel with the inputvalues and read the output with a connection between R and Excel? thanks

Comment: yes there are a few ways to run r script from within excel: https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-million-ways-to-connect-r-and-excel/

Comment: @ Shinobi_Atobe. That's great. I need to call the neural network once a second. Do you expect this will run smooth and stable with such a setup with R, package RExcel and Excel? thanks

Comment: It's not really my area so I'm not sure. Maybe you should create a separate question for it and see if anyone else could help

Comment: @ Shinobi_Atobe Thanks for your advice, I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can program a neural net in Excel. First, you can calibrate the neural net and export the coefficients in an Excel file. Afterwards, you would need to write the code with the activation functions in the Excel file. I present below a code that allows you to calibrate a neural net and export the parameters to the Excel file.

```
library(neuralnet)
library(openxlsx)

nn <- neuralnet(Species == "setosa" ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris, linear.output = FALSE)
weigths_By_Layers <- nn$weights[[1]]
nb_Layers <- length(weigths_By_Layers)

wbk <- createWorkbook()

for(i in 1 : nb_Layers)
{
  sheet_Names <- paste0("Parameters_Layer_", i)
  addWorksheet(wbk,  sheet_Names)
  writeData(wbk, sheet = sheet_Names, x = weigths_By_Layers[[i]])
}

saveWorkbook(wbk, "neural_Net_Parameters.xlsx")
```